# How to get a section of text in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following text in ruby, i want to extract only the part between ---- and ---- (the content) but I'm not able to do that, I tried with regex using:

```
mystring.match(/^-*(.*?)^-*/m)[1]
```

this is the text:

```
Congrats! You just got a new contact lead

Here's the information your contact submitted:

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Name: testing
    Email: test123@gmail.com
    Mensaje: hello
this is a nice test

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For your convenience, we have automatically added this contact and message to your account.

Best of luck!
- LeadABC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try...

```
mystring.match(/-+(.*?)-+/m)[1]
```

[RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/67a32).

However, this will break if there is a `-` in your *contents*. It would probably be more robust if you accepted a bare minimum, such as 10 `-` characters. You can use the `{10,}` quantifier to do this.

```
mystring.match(/(-{10,})(.*?)\1/m)[2]
```

[RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/52afd/2).

This version also ensures the number of `-` matched are *balanced* (if it matched 16 `-` characters at the start, it must match 16 `-` characters at the end too).

Comment: @oldergod Multi-line mode. Make the `.` match newlines.

Comment: Nice usage of the back reference. Note, it assumes that both `-----` lines are of equal length.

Answer (score 0):

You content might contain `-`, but you still can match line-ends with `^` and `$`, so try:

```
mystring.match(/(^-{84}$)(.*?)\1/m)[2]
```

Comment: ...And just hope the recipient didn't delete one :)

Comment: Hehe, yeah, if it comes from a user. If it's system generated, then you can go super precise like this.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting it with a line that consists only of consecutive hyphens with possible white characters at the ends will make it robust.

```
mystring.split(/^[ \t]*-+[ \t]*$/)[1]
```